# How to integrate a web page module in a linux console solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, console-application

I have to implement several funcionalities on an embedded board running linux (yocto-project). In order to do so I created a .Net 5 solution (due to our VS version) that works with a central hub module that instantiates several dedicated modules (I/O management, communication, etc).

Now I need a webpage in order to let the user do their configurations and gather some basic data (like current IP address and similar). What is the most elegant way to do it? I have no experience on web development, I thought it could be possible to launch the application as a separate task but I'm not sure.

I would try something like this:

```
//Inside Main
Task.Run(() =>Webserver.CreateHostBuilder(null).Build().Run());
```

The `CreateHostBuilder` part comes from a tutorial where a simple webserver with razor pages was created.

My targets are:

1. To be able to run the webpage without eating too many resources from the CPU (it's a tiny Cortex-A7 i.MX 6ULL)
2. To use the web as a module and interact with other modules through events or whatever is available

Could you give me some directions?
Thanks!

Comment: Very Simply : A Webpage is HTML (text) that is sent to a browser.  Normally you just need to navigate to a URL or File.  See : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/how-to-develop-web-sites-on-linux/

Comment: Yes, I get that, but for instance in this webpage I want to let user change settings, i.e. the IP Address which is managed by the network module in the console project. So I am looking for a way to tie everything together as nice as possible.

Comment: Normally a website is run as a service where the is one IP address (URL).  There is a base URL (http://myserver/mywebpage) and Routes are extensions to the URL.  If you want the users to have their own options you can do it in a config file that can be changed without recompiling.